# Anonymous class method access

Tags: java

Is it any possible way to access the anonySubClassMethod method?
If no why Java compiler allowing to create this method?

```
abstract interface AnonyIfc {
   public abstract void methodIfc ();
}

public class AnonyImplementation {
   public static void main (String... a) {
      AnonyIfc obj = new AnonyIfc(){
         public void methodIfc() {
            System.out.println("methodIfc");
         }
         public void anonySubClassMethod() {
            System.out.println("anonySubClassMethod");
         }
      };
      //obj.anonySubClassMethod()  won't be visible since refering sub class
      //                           method with super class reference
   }
 }
```

Update
 
From Francis Upton I understood that anonySubClassMethod can be used within the anonymous class. So can i expect the java compiler to restrict the access specifier to private for anonySubClassMethod? Hope there will be a reason for this public specifier also. just curious.

Comment: An interface itself and methods within the interface are by default ***abstract*** hence, there is no meaning to use such a keyword with them. You can always avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method can be called from within your anonymous class. And the more typical use of this construct is cases where you are implementing an interface (for a GUI listener for example), so the method will be known since it's an implementation of the interface the caller is expecting.

Comment: Thanks. So can i expect compiler to restrict the access modifier for anonySubClassMethod is only private?

Comment: No, in the case where the object implements an interface that is used, the method will be required to be public. This is the usual case as I mentioned in my answer. The fact that you can't call the method because it's not defined in the class does not have anything to do with it's visibility, it's because it's not known to the caller. If you look at the generated code, it actually creates another class with a $n suffix.

Answer (score 9):

As others have noted, the method might be called from within the class. The only way to call it from outside the class (besides using reflection) would be like the following:

```
new Object() {
    void doSomething() {
        //code
    }
}.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use reflection to access it, but otherwise there's no way to get to it from any code outside the anonymous class. But that doesn't mean you couldn't access it from *within* the class.  `methodIfc()` could call it, and so that's why the compiler can't easily declare it to be dead code.

Comment: Reflection also explains why there's some sense in the language allowing public methods in anonymous classes that aren't defined in the interfaces/superclass.

Comment: @Ernest, Reflection is not the only way to access it. Look at Paul's answer.

Comment: @Pacerier -- did you actually *read* this answer? In particular, the second and third sentences?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill, You stated that we can use it within the anonymous class itself, or we can use reflection. And you stated that there's no other way. You are wrong, because we can access it outside of the anonymous class too, as Paul's answer have demonstrated.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the compiler does not restrict the visibility of `anonySubClassMethod` to private is that this method can be accessed by means of reflection:
    `obj.getClass().getMethod("anonySubClassMethod").invoke(obj)`

If you don't want to use reflection, there's no way to invoke this method.

Comment: There is a way without using reflection. Look at Paul's answer.