# Using an arbitrarily defined method of an anonymous interface

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("C:\\someFile.txt") {
        public void doStuff() {
            // Do some stuff
        }   
    };

    file.doStuff(); // "Cannot resolve method"
}
```

When we try to call our newly defined method `doStuff()`, it isn't possible. The reason for this is that `file` is declared as an object of type `File` and not as an instance of our new, anonymous child class.

So, my question is, is there any 'nice' way  to achieve this behaviour? Other than the obvious (which is to just, declare the class properly).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697971/anonymous-class-method-access - You're not "overriding" anything here, which is the more usual use of anonymous classes, so your method would only be available within your anonymous class or if you did something using reflection

Comment: `extend` is nice enough for me.

Comment: You can use an anonymous class but you can't have an anonymous interface.

Comment: ... what's the purpose of your example? I believe it would be *clearer* if you put the `// Do some stuff` code directly in the `main` block, instead of hiding it into an anonymous class and *then* calling it.

Comment: There's no purpose to the entire example (i.e. it doesn't *do* anything, just 'stuff'). It was an example of what I was asking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not possible, because you are trying to call the method subclass on super class reference. And that method is not defined in super class itself. The anonymous class is just a subclass of `File` there.

However, a workaround is to go through reflection:

```
file.getClass().getMethod("doStuff").invoke(file);
```

The [`getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method will return the runtime type of `file`, and then you can get the method for that class using [`Class#getMethod()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) method.

Well, I'm not a big fan of reflection myself. A better way would of course be to create a class by extending the super class, if you are going to do these kinds of stuff. It would be really a pain in the head, working your way out using reflection, for what can be easily done using a simple modification.

Comment: `file.getClass().getMethod("doStuff").invoke();` is not work here.

Comment: @Ruchira. What do you mean by that?

Comment: RE: Your edit about the perils of reflection: That's fine, I'm not about to start using reflection everywhere. This was purely a 'theoretical' question, and this is the best answer.

Comment: Add file as a parameter to invoke().

Answer (score 7):

The nice way is not to use anonymous inner class in your case but define your own class that extends `File` and add any methods you need there.

```
class StuffedFile extends File {
    // implement all needed constructors
    public void doStuff() { /*.....*/}
}
```

Now you can use it as following:

```
MyFile f = new MyFile("...");
f.doStuff();
```

However whole this attempt to extend `File` does not sound as a good design. Create other class that can accept file and do stuff on it. You will achieve better encapsulation and code reusability.

EDIT
Obviously you can use reflection to call any method you want but I cannot call this "nice solution". I can call this "possible workaround".

Comment: The code was just an example, I'm not doing anything with File. Also I was looking for a 'cleaner' syntax without having to create a new class. I know that I can just extend File.

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer, to change MyFile to the defined Class StuffedFile?

Comment: +1 reflection is slow and with the additional code for `catch` for the checked exceptions of `invoke` this is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

The nearest I have been able to get to your level of succinctness is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  abstract class FileThatDoesStuff extends File {
    // Need a constructor that takes a String because File has one.
    public FileThatDoesStuff(String filePath) {
      super(filePath);
    }
    // It also does stuff.
    public abstract void doStuff();
  }
  FileThatDoesStuff file = new FileThatDoesStuff("C:\\someFile.txt") {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
      // Do some stuff
    }

  };
  file.doStuff(); // "Can resolve method"
}
```

I have to admit I wish I could do:

```
abstract class DoesStuff<T> extends T {
  public abstract void doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Curmudgeon: C# offers this with extension methods (the last behaviour you state there). One of the reasons I love C# :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access that method. But I don't know why you would ever want to do this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new File("C:\\someFile.txt") {
      public void doStuff() {
          // Do some stuff
      }   
   }.doStuff();
}
```