# How can I access this anonymous class method in java?

Tags: java

How can I access this anonymous class method in Java and I getting error on below. What is the use of anonymous classes in Java? Can we say that usage of anonymous class is one of the advantages of java?

```
class Test1
{
    public Test1()
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
}

class Test extends Test1
{  
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Test1 obj1= new Test1()
        {
            public void test1()
            {
                System.out.println("Yes A");
            }
        };
        obj1.test1(); // here i am getting error 
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error trace you are getting, it will help to solve the problem.

Comment: It is possible to access that method. But I don't know why you would ever want to do this. 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Test1(){
         public void test1(){
            System.out.println("Yes A");
         }
      }.test1();
    }

An alternative:

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      abstract class Test2 extends Test1 {
         public abstract void test1();
      }
      final Test2 test2 = new Test2(){
         @Override
         public void test1(){
            System.out.println("Yes A");
         }
      };
      test2.test1();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a parent class reference you can only access methods declared in parent class. 
when you do

```
Test1 obj1= new Test1(){
      public void test1(){
        System.out.println("Yes A");
      }
};
obj1.test1(); // here i am getting error
```

you are creating an anonymous instance of a `class extending Test1` which is referred by the parent type reference.

so the method test1() actually is a new method which belongs to the extending class and not an overridden method of Test1, so it cant be called using obj1.

Answer (score 0):

You have not anonymous class there.

You got error, because you try to invoke method `test1()` thats not declared in class `Test1` and your object `obj1` instance of `Test1` class.

About anonymous classes try to read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it this way. `obj1` is of type `Test1` and this class doesn't have `test1` method.

Comment: Sure, but you can't access it via superclass type. Anyway, I marked it as duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656107/using-an-arbitrarily-defined-method-of-an-anonymous-interface

Answer (score 0):

When I am trying to compile your  program, I am getting error at line `obj1.test1();` as *The method test1() is undefined for the type Test1*.

You can solve this by creating a `test1()` method in `Test1` class.

```
class Test1 {
  public Test1() {
     System.out.println("Yes");
  }
  public void test1() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is an example of inheritance it is not an example of anonymous class.
Here Test1 obj1= new Test1() you are creating object of Test1 class and trying to invoke method test1() on that object it means test1() method should be present in Test1 class.

And anonymous class you can see here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html
[How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)